# How to match a string containing the character "$" with grep?

Tags: bash, grep, special-characters

How to match strings that contain `$` character?

Example - by the following `grep` doesn't return the match.

```
  param="ambari_parameter$"
  echo "ambari_parameter$" | grep $param
  echo "ambari_parameter$" | grep "$param"
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In this case, the string in `$param` will be interpreted as a regular expression.  This expression contains a `$` which anchors the `ambari_parameter` in the pattern to the end of the match.  Since `ambari_parameter$` in the input data does not contain `ambari_parameter` at the very end (due to the `$` at the end of the string), it won't match.

You could just escape the `$` as `\$` in the pattern (`\\$` in a double quoted string), or place the `$` in a bracketed group as `[$]`, but since you seem to want to do a string match rather than a regular expression match, it may be more appropriate to use `-F`:

```
echo 'ambari_parameter$' | grep -F -e "$param"
```

Using `grep -F` makes `grep` treat the given pattern as a string rather than as a regular expression. Each character in the pattern will therefore be match literally, even the `$` at the end.

I also used `-e` here to force `grep` to recognize the following argument as a pattern. This is necessary if `$param` starts with a dash (`-`). It's generally good to use `-e` whenever the pattern you match with is given in a variable.

To further require that the *whole* input line matches the complete string, add `-x`:

```
echo 'ambari_parameter$' | grep -xF -e "$param"
```

If `$param` is `ambari_parameter$`, then this will not match the string `_ambari_parameter$` or `ambari_parameter$100` (but *will* match if `-x` is left out).

Answer (score 8):

If you have a whole pattern you want to match literally [then don't treat it as a regular expression](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/387409/11938). If you *do* need to match a literal `$` in a regular expression,  use `\$`.

Like `.`, `\`, and several other punctuation characters, `$` is a [metacharacter](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) in regular expressions. The `$` character matches [the empty string at the end of a line](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) (so `x$` matches `x` but only at the end of a line). If your pattern doesn't contain *any* metacharacters, then you don't need to treat it as a regular expression and you should use `grep -F` [as Kusalananda explains](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/387409/11938).

*If* you really do need to match a `$` or any other metacharacter literally in a regular expression, escape it with the `\` metacharacter. To match a literal `$` write `\$`, to match a literal `\` write `\\`, and so forth.

```
param='ambari_parameter\$'
echo "ambari_parameter$" | grep "$param"
```

When you assign to `param` in the shell, enclose the regular expression in single quotes (`'` `'`) as shown above, because `$` and `\` also have special meanings in most shells, including all Bourne-style shells (you tagged [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)). [`\` in shells](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Escape-Character) works basically the same as in regular expressions. (`$` doesn't; it's used for various [shell expansions/substitutions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions), especially [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)).

Unquoted, or even in [double quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Double-Quotes), `\$` indicates a literal `$` in the shell, which is then passed to `grep` as `$` which `grep` interprets as a regular expression metacharacter. Enclosing it in single quotes prevents this. You could alternatively write `\\\$`--or sometimes just `\\$`--but that's confusing.

Answer (score 2):

You should escape the special characters in case you are looking for exact match of them as this ways:

if it's in single quote, one escape is required.

```
grep 'parameter\$'
```

if it's in double quote or not quoted, one escape more is required.

```
grep "parameter\\$" #or
grep parameter\\$
```

Note that any space within match if not quoted, should be escaped as well.

```
grep para\ meter\\$
```